# Partial ASP.NET WEB FROM Published Web Application Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **ASP.NET WEB FROM/MVC** web app named SAMPLE .Wherever i publish this web app using visual studio 2013 a build file is generated SAMPLE.dll *in \bin folder and other files(.aspx,.js etc)*. No problem to deploy it to IIS 8.5 .

Let i have 2 module .If i change in module one in SAMPLE i have to redeploy whole App to IIS. I need to shut down my whole app for one module  .If project contain 10 or more module then i need to down the whole system( one bug fixed .cs file to down whole system !!!!!!).

So my question is  what is proper way to develop a large system in asp.net web form such a way if i have 10 or more module then update one module ,that does not cause to down time of other modules.

Does **ASP.NET WEB FROM/MVC** web app supports hot patching and how ?

If not any design patterns or architecture to achieve this goal in **asp.net web form/MVC** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say if you have 10 modules and all needs to be work independently then there would be 1 web project and 9 class libraries, and this web project will contain reference for all 9 projects. So say you have made any change in 4th module then just rebuild the solution, then select the dll of the project you have edited and upload only this single dll and you are done.

Comment: Look like a obvious answer.

Comment: Then the same, every cs file code would be integrated in dll file but if you change the view page i.e. .aspx or .cshtml then you have to upload the page itself

Comment: Any pattern or design structure for developing the library especially on asp.ner WEB FORM?